# Como puedo hacer que un método espere para hacer un return

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En Android Studio, estoy haciendo una petición desde una base de datos usando la librería Volley.

Desde un Activity, necesito llamar a un método que realice la consulta a la Base de Datos y me retorne el resultado para ponerlo en un TextView. Pero al llamar al método que contiene la solicitud (que está en otra clase), este retorna la variable vacía inmediatamente, sin esperar a que lleguen los datos.

Este es el método al que llamo:

```
private String traerDatos(){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    int size = response.length();
                    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.get(i).toString());
                            String datoTraido = jsonObject.getString("title");
                            titulo = datoTraido;
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Datos.this, "Ha ocurrido un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
    solicitud.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    return titulo;
}
```

Ya intenté colocar un Handler para esperar a que la variable no esté vacía, pero al colocar el return dentro del mismo, no lo reconoce como return de ese método.

También hice que se ejecute otro método dentro del onResponse, luego de traer un dato. Pero no sirve de mucho por que no encuentro forma de que el contenido de esa variable vuelva al método del Activity que mostrará dicho contenido en la pantalla.

Aún soy nuevo en esto, así que perdón si estoy cometiendo algún error obvio, pero he estad buscando una forma por días

Comment: Volley trabaja de forma asíncrona, por eso no sirve de nada poner un `return`. Debes usar un callback (esto suele ser un poco más complicado si estás empezando) o, desde dentro del `onResponse()` llamar a un método pasándole el dato de la respuesta si estuvieras en la misma clase. En cambio, si estás en otra clase, debes pasarlo de algún modo, por ejemplo en un `Intent`. Si piensas usar Volley desde varios puntos lo ideal sería programarlo como un servicio y usar Inyección de Dependencias, esto es relativamente fácil usando Hilt, aunque en ese caso, sería mejor usar Retrofit en vez de Volley.

Comment: No caigas en la tentación de *hacer que el método espere hasta que la petición termine*, es una pésima idea, por varios motivos: 1. No sabes cuánto tiempo tardará la petición; 2. Pararlo todo mientras la petición se complete bloquearía la interfaz de usuario, resultando en una pésima UX; 3. Las aplicaciones móviles deben estar pensadas para procesar varias cosas al mismo tiempo, dentro y fuera de la App que estás programando ... Por eso te recomendé Retrofit, combinado con Hilt, porque te ayudarán a programar según las actuales recomendaciones de Android, aplicando cosas como ...

Comment: ... Componentes de Arquitectura, patrón MVVM, etc. Esas herramientas te harán todo más fácil, y tendrás una App con una arquitectura sana, más fluida y más fácil de mantener. El único escollo es que la curva de aprendizaje puede ser empinada, sobre todo si estás empezando, pero vale la pena, porque no será tiempo perdido. [Este es un buen ejemplo](https://github.com/abhinav0612/Pokemon) en el que se usa Hilt + Retrofit + MVVM y cosas más avanzadas, como una BD local.